# How to read yaml properties using javascript

Tags: javascript, yaml

```
mapmarker :
     source : D.marker_data
     type : MapMarker
     region: Pune
     size : 4
     fill_color : Blue
     leader_name : leadername
     markers :
     - circlemarker :
         type: circle_marker
         latlong: 'abc'
     - connector_marker :
         type: icon_marker
         latlong: 'pqr'
     - icon_marker :
         type: connector_marker
         latlong: 'xyz'
```

Here from yaml file I am able to access property values like config.color in javascript and I am getting its color.But how to get the property values like latlong from different markers ? I have following code

config = this.config;
                self = this;

```
            l=config.markers.length;
            for(var k=0;k<l;k++)
            {

             console.log(config.markers[k]);

            }
```

and it gives output like:

```
Object { circlemarker={...}}
Object { connector_marker={...}}
Object { icon_marker={...}}
```

But I want all properties under individual object like latlong value from each marker.

Comment: and what outputs console.log(config.markers[k].type) for example ? or console.log(JSON.stringify(config.markers[k]) or console.dir(config.markers[k]) ?

Comment: It is giving type is not defined

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(config.markers[k]) gives  output like {"circlemarker":{"latlong":"abc","type":"circle_marker"}}

Comment: so you have the full representation of the object and you can access !

Comment: but how to access this represenation? this is the issue for me.

Comment: hm just add another for loop that iterates over config.markers[k]

Comment: or try config.markers[k][0].type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code snippest I found as my solution :

```
 for (var a = 0; a < obj.length; a++) {
        var key = Object.keys(obj[a])[0];
        var latlong = obj[a][key][1];
        console.log(latlong);
    }
```

Comment: I've cleaned up a few of your recent answers which contained no useful information except links to plnkr.co. Please don't post answers which depend on off-site links to be meaningful.